# How should I get the port number for SQL Server 2008 from query when I am connecting to SQL Server using VPN

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am accessing SQL Server over a VPN.

Is there a way to use a sql query to find the port number I am communicating over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the default instance it would be:

```
DECLARE @tcp_port nvarchar(5)

EXEC xp_regread
 @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
 @key = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLSERVER\SUPERSOCKETNETLIB\TCP',
 @value_name = 'TcpPort',
 @value = @tcp_port OUTPUT

select @tcp_port
```

For a named instance it would be:

```
DECLARE @tcp_port nvarchar(5)

EXEC xp_regread
 @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
 @key = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSSQLSERVER\PutYourInstanceNameHere\MSSQLSERVER\SUPERSOCKETNETLIB\TCP',
 @value_name = 'TcpPort',
 @value = @tcp_port OUTPUT

select @tcp_port
```

Comment: Hey it is working at Local but when i tried this on through VPN 
i am getting NULL return.
can you please help me here...

Comment: @VikrantMore so you VPN'd into the network and ran that through your local SSMS query window?  My guess is that it would look through the registries on your local machine (and not find anything).  You probably have to remote desktop into the server to get the right information.  That's what I'm thinking.